# Dart can't find BrowserClient

Tags: angular, dart

I'm sure this is a basic mistake, but I seem unable to build an Angular2  application when using a BrowserClient in Dart.

main.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/platform/browser.dart';
import 'package:dartblog/app_component.dart';
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';

void main(){
  bootstrap(
      AppComponent,
      const [BrowserClient]
  );
}
```

I did alter my pubspec.yaml; the important part:

```
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
    resolved_identifiers:
      BrowserClient: 'package:http/browser_client.dart'
```

The error I am getting when running `pub build` is the following:

```
[Error from Dart2JS on dartblog|web/main.dart]:
web/main.template.dart:15:1:
Can't read 'package:http/browser_client.dart' (Could not find asset http|lib/browser_client.dart.).
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Warning from Dart2JS]:
web/main.dart:6:40:
Cannot resolve 'BrowserClient'.
  bootstrapStatic(AppComponent, const [BrowserClient], () { ngStaticInit.initReflector(); });
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS]:
web/main.dart:6:40:
Not a compile-time constant.
  bootstrapStatic(AppComponent, const [BrowserClient], () { ngStaticInit.initReflector(); });
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am trying to make get requests with Dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BrowserClient` in not injectable AFAICT.

try this:

```
BrowserClient newBrowserClient() => new BrowserClient();
...
const Provider(BrowserClient, useFactory: newBrowserClient)
```

Obviously, you need to have the `http` package in your pub dependencies.